# grails-spring-security-rest OAuth OAuthException: Response body is incorrect

Tags: grails-spring-security

The plugin throws the following error when trying to sign in with facebook.

error:500,
message:org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this: '{"access_token":"EAAOWKGC6MDcBAB9ZAka1zEc1","token_type":"bearer"}', error_description:org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Response body is incorrect. Can't extract a token from this: '{"access_token":"EAAOWKGC6M","token_type":"bearer"}', error_code:OAuthException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem customizing the Facebookclient. (workarround)
bug details: https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/issues/327

Put files in your src/main/groovy, (recommend create other package  src/main/groovy/springSecurity)

Files: https://gist.github.com/sergioz95/1266c2a29b4d00094fe18423b350aa34

and reference the new facebookClient in application.groovy

```
grails {
  plugin {
    springsecurity {
        rest {
            oauth {
                facebook {
                    client = YOUR_PACKAGE.FacebookClient
                    ....
```

Note: you can change the facebook url(because already is used 2.2)